# CNN audio classifier trained with 3 classes and the sum of the prediction should be less than one

Tags: python, keras, classification, conv-neural-network

I built a CNN audio classifier with 3 classes. My problem is that their are more than 3 classes, e.g. a fourth could be "noise". 
So when I call be prediction the sum of these 3 classes is always 1.

`prediction = model.predict([X])`

Is it somehow possible to extract the accuracy of each class so the sum of these accuracies is less then 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a softmax activation function you are forcing the outputs to sum to 1, thereby making a relative confidence score between your classes. Perhaps, without knowing more about your data and application, a "1 vs all" type scheme would work better for your purposes. For example, each class could have a sigmoid activation function and you could pick the highest prediction but if that prediction doesn't score high enough on a sensitivity threshold then none of the classes are predicted and as such is empty or implicitly "noise."

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I needed.